# Independent Subscales

Tags: scales

What properties should there of a subscale to be used independently of the whole scale?
I am looking for a scale that measures a specific perceived parenting style, but there is no scale for it. Instead every other scale has multiple constructs. Now, the issue is the number of items along with other constructs of no interest. So, is it possible to just one subscale from the whole scale?